# Virtual machine works slow

Tags: virtualbox

I'm using virtual box to run Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
The problem is that the vm runs slow. I've read a lot of guides to improve it's performence, but nothing worked so far.

My computer details:
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6200U CPU @2.30GHz,
Ram: 12 Gb,
64 bit.

I've allocated 2 cores out of 4 to the machine, and about 9 GB of RAM, and it still works slow. By slow I mean that when I type, the machine recognizes the typing after about 5 seconds, most of the time. In addition, even when I run the vm, the original windows works fine and quick, so i suspect that the vm dosen't use the whole power it can get.

The virtualization in the BIOS was already enabled.

What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: Could you add what host OS and VirtualBox version you are using? Did you change anything else in the configuration?

Comment: Did you enable hardware acceleration in your BIOS ?

Comment: Did you have checked VT-x/AMD-V in VirtualBox settings tab System -> Acceleration?

Comment: @Panther as I wrote, yes, but maybe you are talking about something else?

Comment: @E.F.Nijboer I have windows 7 as my OS, and the Virtual Box's version is 5.2.0. I hadn't change nothing but th RAM and the Cores.

Comment: @N0rbert yes, it was already checked

Comment: Does blue chip icon from [this image](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/images/vm-hostkey.png) ([from VirtualBox documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#keyb_mouse_normal)) differs from yours? Is it grayed out? Also you should enable 2D and 3D graphics acceleration and install guest additions.

Comment: @N0rbert do you mean to the left one? I have the same.

Comment: If chip with **V** is blue and you enabled 2D and 3D video acceleration and installed guest additions I have no new ideas.

Comment: @N0rbert I enabled 3D. It says that 2D belongs to a case that windows is the guest, so it won't let me to enable this. And I tried to install the guest additions, but it failed in some parts.

Comment: Hi Amir, can you check hyper-v is enabled on your windows version. If that is the case then VirtualBox cannot take advantage of any hardware acceleration because it is hogged and not available.  You can find it under Configuration -> programs -> turn windows features on or off. Turn it off if enabled, as usual first a reboot and then try virtualbox again to see if it helped. Good luck!